# Google Fonts package for flutter fails to load font in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have used the Google fonts package in my flutter application 
https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

The app runs fine on debug mode and the fonts load without any issue.

But, however, when I build and run the application in release mode, the fonts fail to load. Most of the time the app crashes and sometimes the default Roboto font is loaded.

There are some issues open on GitHub but any of that doesn't fix my issue.
I tried cleaning the build folder, rechecked `pubspec.yaml` file, checked the `google_fonts` package version, verified internet connectivity, and even recreated the project. But nothing solved the issue.

version:

```
google_fonts: ^1.1.0
```

I got this error log while running the app using `flutter run --release` command 
Here's the error I got:

```
I/flutter (17872): Error: google_fonts was unable to load font Montserrat-SemiBold because the following exception occured:
I/flutter (17872): Exception: Failed to load font with url: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/5f82f6e55db43e905c6ab9d04395566b243c41798d6a53545ffbd10ed6c424c4.ttf
I/flutter (17872): Error: google_fonts was unable to load font Montserrat-Medium because the following exception occured:
I/flutter (17872): Exception: Failed to load font with url: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/cec0f6e0bfbfaa352eb189f0eb220916dd278b02aaf824be87055ba5cc38d58b.ttf
I/flutter (17872): Error: google_fonts was unable to load font Montserrat-Regular because the following exception occured:
I/flutter (17872): Exception: Failed to load font with url: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/470e93c06a9fffa6851375f54047917a9d774ed6027d9f044cd1bc8d4cd5630b.ttf
```

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet? Also uninstalling the application that you're using and running `flutter clean` may help you out.

Comment: I have already done both, but it still persists.

Comment: Adding the Internet Permission in Android Manifest File Under main directory solved the issue on release mode.

Answer (score 5):

This error can have many reasons but I think one of these two is the case:

1. If it only happens on android then maybe you didn't add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest file.
2. You're in a country where this service is banned

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the internet, and it's already present in manifest.xml. If the service is banned, then It shouldn't have run in the debug mode right, but it did. So, I think that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You're right I forgot that it's working in debugging mode. I can't think of anything else @BalaGanesh

Answer (score 1):

`Google Fonts` are fetched from the internet in the runtime. So for this to work you need to have active internet connection.

To overcome this,You can download the font from `google font` and make it available in the `asset folder` i.e `offline` and change the code from

```
// Online Code
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font'
  style: GoogleFonts.hammersmithOne(),
),
```

to

```
// Offline Code
Text(
  'This is hammersmithOne from Google Font',
   style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'hammersmithOne') // This is loaded from assets
),
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.